# Running windows service in separate thread and use autofac for DI

Tags: multithreading, windows-services, autofac

I'm trying to create a long running windows service, so I need to run the actual worker class on a separate thread, to avoid the "service did not respond in a timely fashion" error when I right click and select start in Windows Service Manager.

The worker class ("NotificationProcess") has a whole raft of dependencies and I'm using Autofac to satisfy these.

I'm really not sure how to set up Autofac for the worker class. At the moment I'm getting errors telling me that the DbContext has been disposed when I go to use it in the "Execute" method of the worker class.

I guess I'm looking for how to write a windows service and use a new thread for the worker class with dependencies satisfied by autofac.

I've googled and can't find any examples of this.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Here's what I've got so far...

Program.cs:

```
    static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var container = ServiceStarter.CreateAutoFacContainer())
        {
            var service = container.Resolve<NotificationService>();
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                service.Debug();
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(container.Resolve<NotificationService>());
            }
        }
```

The Service class:

```
public partial class NotificationService : ServiceBase
{
    private NotificationProcess _app;
    readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public NotificationService(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _app = _lifetimeScope.Resolve<NotificationProcess>();
        _app.Start();
    }
```

The worker class:

```
    public class NotificationProcess
{
    private Thread _thread;

    private readonly IBankService _bankService;
    private readonly IRateService _rateService;
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    private readonly IRateChangeSubscriberService _rateChangeSubscriberService;
    private readonly IRateChangeNotificationService _rateChangeNotificationService;
    private readonly ILogManager _logManager;

    public NotificationProcess(IBankService bankService, ILogManager logManager, IRateService rateService, IEmailService emailService, 
        IRateChangeSubscriberService rateChangeSubscriberService, IRateChangeNotificationService rateChangeNotificationService)
    {
        _bankService = bankService;
        _rateService = rateService;
        _emailService = emailService;
        _rateChangeSubscriberService = rateChangeSubscriberService;
        _rateChangeNotificationService = rateChangeNotificationService;
        _logManager = logManager;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            var rateChangeToNotify = _rateService.GetRateChangesForNotification();

            foreach (var rateChange in rateChangeToNotify)
            {
                 //do whatever business logic.....
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is actually simple: use scoping! You should do the following:

1. Register all services (such as `DbContext`) that should live for the duration of a request or action with the LifetimeScope lifestyle. You'll usually have a timer in your windows service. Each 'pulse' can be considered a request.
2. On the beginning of each request begin a lifetime scope.
3. Within that scope, resolve the root object from the object graph and call its method.
4. Dispose the scope.

In your case that means you need to change your design, since `NotificationService` is resolved once and its dependencies are reused on another thread. This is a [no-no](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#multi-threaded-applications) in dependency injection land.

Here's an alternative design:

```cs
// This method is called on a background thread 
// (possibly in a timely manner)
public void Run()
{
    try
    {
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var service = scope.Resolve<NotificationService>();
            service.Execute();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // IMPORTANT: log exception. 
        // Not logging an exception will leave us in the dark.
        // Not catching the exception will kill our service 
        // because we run in a background thread.
    }
}
```

Using a lifetime scope allows you to get a fresh `DbContext` for every request and it would even allow you to run requests in parallel (with each request its own `DbContext`).

Comment: Cool, so you're saying don't even create the container in the main method of Program.cs rather create the container in the processing class? Then begin a lifetime scope with the run method as you've outlined above?

Comment: did you not mean the Run would resolve NotificationProcess? NotificationService doesn't have an Execute method?

Comment: You should create the container directly at startup, but only create lifetime scopes for each 'request'. So don't resolve anything before the request, or at least don't resolve anything that gets reused for all requests.

Comment: what I am currently facing is that within the process method in the windows service (I am using sqldependency to trigger the action), in there, the works will be run in parallel. so each thread will need it's own dbcontext, that means if setting up the instanceperlifetimescope, the scope will need to be resolved within the action, not even the main process.

Comment: if you are just doing single thread processing in the wakeup call, you might want to use [atlas](https://atlas.codeplex.com/) for the windows service. worth a try since it supports autofac out-of-the-box.

Comment: then the problem is the instance resolved is not really per thread since it's resolved with code like this : using(var scope = container.beginlifetimescope()){ Isometerface instance = scope.resolve<Isomeinterface>();}, keep in mind that when the scope is disposed, all instance within the scope that implements IDisposable will be disposed! so it's instance within that using block scope. anyone run into the same scenario?

Comment: @Steven What package, namespace is the scope.Resolve<T> method in?

Comment: @Steven Sorry, when i saw you posted this, i assumed this was a Simple Injector answer!

Comment: @gdp in Simple Injector, you can simply resolve from the container; much easier.